# How to find the range of a joint distribution after transformation?

Tags: probability, statistics

If X and Y are independent and identically distributed uniform random variables on (0,1), compute the joint density of (a) U = X + Y, V = X/Y; (b) U = X, V = X/Y; (c) U = X+Y, V = X/(X+Y);

I know how to compute the joint density, however I am having trouble identifying the range of U and V after the transformation.

Comment: @Rowan Just to check if i am correct for (c): if 1 < u < 2, then $1-\frac{1}{u} < v < \frac{1}{u}$; if 0 < u < 1, then $0 < v < 1$. If 0 < v < 0.5, then $0 < u < \frac{1}{1-v}$; if 0.5 < v < 1, then $0 < u < \frac{1}{v}$

Comment: Yes, it's true. But is there a typo mistake in case two?

Comment: @Rowan which typo?

Comment: Uhh… in my small screen iPhone, u and $v$ looks pretty much the same. No typo mistakes.